# Algebraic closed field theory is $\Sigma_1$ (hence decidable)

Tags: logic, field-theory, model-theory, decidability

In Bruno Poizat's *Model Theory* I found the following proof of ACF's decidability:

1) ACF is $\Sigma_1$, i.e. the set of sentences which are proved by ACF is definable by a $\Sigma_1$ formula.

2) The complement of ACF is also $\Sigma_1$.

3) As a consequence, ACF is $\Delta_1$, hence decidable.

Points (2-3) are clear. Could someone help me proving point (1)? Proving that the set of sentences that *axiomatize* ACF is $\Sigma_1$ is sufficient.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Field axioms are finite, then add a schema "every nonzero polynomial has a root". And a schema for characteristics.

Comment: Yes, but how to prove that such axiomatisation in $Sigma_1$? Perhaps I'm missing something really obvious...

Comment: Asaf Karagila comment can be translated in a computer program that prints out all aioms. By Church thesis, this amounts to proving that the axiomatization is $\Sigma_1$.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is this? The axioms themselves are not $\Sigma_1$ sentences. What's meant is that the *set* of axioms is definable by a $\Sigma_1$ formula (as a set of natural numbers in the language of arithmetic).

Comment: I don't see how you can bypass something along the lines of the usual quantifier elimination argument for the decidability of ACF here. Neither 1) nor 2) is trivial.

Comment: @RobArthan Whether something is trivial is subjective, of course, but 1) is certainly more trivial than 2) - it just follows from the fact that ACF is recursively axiomatized. It's 2) where you need to know completeness of ACFp. I'll post an answer along these lines in a moment.

Comment: (And one way to establish this completeness is QE - but another way is via Vaught's test, since algebraically closed fields are easily seen to be uncountable categorical, once you know about transcendence bases)

Comment: what is $\Sigma_1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are informal descriptions of the $\Sigma_1$ formulas:

(1) There exists a finite set $\Phi$ of axioms of ACF and a proof of $\varphi$ from $\Phi$.

(2) There exists a prime number $p$ and a finite set $\Phi$ of axioms of ACF and a proof of $\lnot\varphi$ from $\Phi \cup \{p = 0\}$, *or* there exists a finite set $\{p_1,\dots,p_k\}$ of prime numbers and a finite set $\Phi$ of axioms of ACF and a proof of $\lnot\varphi$ from $\Phi \cup \{p_1 \neq 0\mid 1\leq i\leq k\}$.

To check that these formulas are $\Sigma_1$, you just need to know that that you can recognize axioms of ACF and proofs in a $\Delta_0$ (i.e. recursive) way.

As for why they work: (1) is completely straightforward, but (2) is a bit more involved. The point is that $\varphi$ is not a consequence of ACF, if and only if it's false in some algebraically closed field $K$, if and only if $\lnot\varphi$ is a consequence of $\text{Th}(K)$. And the complete consistent theories containing ACF are exactly ACF$_p$, where $p$ is a prime number or $0$.

Comment: Thank you! In point (1) we don't use anything of ACF, do we? It would work for every theory, right?

Comment: @W.Rether Every theory with a recursively enumerable set of axioms.